# Indicate the re-occurrence of a from_number in a to_number field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a phone network there are callers: `from_number` and receivers: `to_numbers`.
I need a list of all distinct aussi numbers out of the `from_number` and `to_numbers` columns/ variables. The list needs to act as a filter and indicate the `direction`, as in 'from' or 'to'. If the number re-occurred at any location in both fields, that is at any location in the `from_number` and at any location of the `to_numbers` field, then this should be indicated as `both`.

I have an example code: the desired outcome as well what I tried:

```
    create table calls 
    (
       call_date date,
       from_number varchar(16),
       to_number varchar(16)
    );
    
    INSERT  calls
  VALUES   ('2020-07-03','619876544',  '022445545'),
         ( '2020-07-03','61123456',  '642445544'), 
         ('2020-07-03','03123456',   '61333333'),
         ('2020-07-03','65123456',   '619876543'),
         ('2020-07-04','642445545',  '61123456'),
         ( '2020-07-04','61333333',  '632445555'),
         ('2020-07-04','642445545',  '049876543'),
         ('2020-07-03','649876543',  '61333333'),
         ( '2020-07-04','612445555',  '022445545');
    
    SELECT   DISTINCT 
                callers.*, 
 
    FROM        calls    callers
```

the desired outcome with the direction : to, from, both:

```
create table calls 
(
   call_date date,
   from_number varchar(16),
   to_number varchar(16),
   direction varchar (8)
);

INSERT  calls
VALUES   ('2020-07-03','619876544',  '022445545', 'from'),
         ( '2020-07-03','61123456',  '642445544', 'both'), 
         ('2020-07-03','03123456',   '61333333', 'both'),
         ('2020-07-03','65123456',   '619876543', 'to'),
         ('2020-07-04','642445545',  '61123456', 'both'),
         ( '2020-07-04','61333333',  '632445555', 'both'),
         ('2020-07-04','642445545',  '049876543', 'none'),
         ('2020-07-03','649876543',  '61333333', 'both'),
         ( '2020-07-04','612445555',  '022445545', 'from');

SELECT   DISTINCT 
            callers.*
        
FROM        calls    callers
```

How can I see, whether a number re-occurred anywhere in [From_Number] AND [To_Number] and set the direction to both in this case? If it only occurred in a from Number, then it should be set to from, if it occurred only in a to number then should be set to : to

what I tried:

```
create table calls 
(
   call_date date,
   from_number varchar(16),
   to_number varchar(16),
   direction varchar (8)
);

INSERT  calls
VALUES   ('2020-07-03','619876544',  '022445545', 'to'),
         ( '2020-07-03','61123456',  '642445544', 'both'), 
         ('2020-07-03','03123456',   '61333333', 'both'),
         ('2020-07-03','65123456',   '619876543', 'to'),
         ('2020-07-04','642445545',  '61123456', 'both'),
         ( '2020-07-04','61333333',  '632445555', 'both'),
         ('2020-07-04','642445545',  '049876543', '0'),
         ('2020-07-03','649876543',  '61333333', 'both'),
         ( '2020-07-04','612445555',  '022445545', 'from');

SELECT   DISTINCT 
            callers.call_date
            ,callers.[From_Number]
            ,callers.[To_Number]
            ,DIRECTION = ISNULL(recipients.From_Number, 'both')
            --,CASE
            --WHEN LEFT (callers.[From_Number] ,2) = '61' then 'from' 
            --WHEN LEFT (callers.[To_Number] ,2)    = '61' then 'to' ELSE '0' END AS  direction1
FROM        calls    callers
LEFT JOIN   calls    recipients 
ON recipients.from_number = callers.to_number;
```

Lent on a previous question it is likely to be something like this.
How can I set the:

```
,DIRECTION = ISNULL(recipients.From_Number, 'both')
```

in a way that it does what I need and DIRECTION can be filtered for to / from / both ?

Comment: What does the value `0` mean for direction? I don't really follow what you're actually after here though, if I am honest; what you describe you want, and then the expected results don't really match. For example, if you want a list of all the numbers in your data, why does your expected results have 2 columns for said numbers and not one?

Comment: why is this `'2020-07-03','619876544',  '022445545', 'to'` consider `TO` ?

Comment: What do you want to show if, for example, the From number only occurs in From, but the To number also occurs in From?

Comment: @Lamu I changed the typos, thank you

Comment: @Charlieface - that will not happen because these are confirmed directional phone calls. So there is only ever going to be an aussi number either in the from or the to. But I want to have them labelled both when a number has occurred anytime in either the from calls or the to calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to unpivot using `apply`:

```
select v.number,
       (case when min(v.direction) = max(v.direction)
             then min(v.direction)
             else 'both'
        end),
       count(*)
from calls c cross apply
     (values (from_number, 'from'),
             (to_number, 'to')
     ) v(number, direction)
group by number;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff thank you for your suggestion. I don't understand though where the min / max direction should come from as the variable direction with the values from/ to and both needs to be created ? I could only think that one could grade the numbers and argue that 61 numbers are the min and 64 numbers the max. But what if I have country codes lower 61 in there. So I am not sure how that can work.

Comment: @Anna . . . This uses the logic you specified in the question:  "If it only occurred in a from Number, then it should be set to from, if it occurred only in a to number then should be set to : to".  I added "all others are `both`".

Answer (score 0):

Given that you say there is only ever one side which starts with `61`, and these are the ones you want to count to establish the direction calls have been made, you can calculate which number to use inside an `APPLY`, then use window functions over that:

```sql
SELECT c.*,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN from_number LIKE '61%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY v.num) > 0
    THEN
      CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN to_number LIKE '61%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY v.num) > 0
        THEN 'both'
        ELSE 'from'
      END
    ELSE
      CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN to_number LIKE '61%' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY v.num) > 0
        THEN 'to'
        ELSE 'none'
      END
  END
FROM calls c
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
  (CASE WHEN from_number LIKE '61%' THEN from_number
        WHEN to_number LIKE '61%' THEN to_number
        END)
) v(num);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00801f7885a58153ce5909035ecbb919)